# Cannot convert System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument.Error:'useridResponse' is an unexpected token.Expectingwhitespace.Line 22, position 88

Tags: xml, powershell, azure-api-management

Getting the below error while calling xml via poweshell script

> Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type
> "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "'useridResponse' is an unexpected
> token. Expecting white space. Line 22, position 88."

My xml looks like

```
 <authentication-managed-identity resource="https://vault.azure.net" />
        </send-request>
        <authentication-basic username="@{ var secret = ((IResponse)context.Variables["useridResponse"]).Body.As<JObject>(); return secret["value"].ToString(); }" password="@{ var secret = ((IResponse)context.Variables["passwordResponse"]).Body.As<JObject>(); return secret["value"].ToString(); }" />
        <set-backend-service base-url="@{ var secret = ((IResponse)context.Variables["backendResponse"]).Body.As<JObject>(); return secret["value"].ToString(); }" />
    </inbound>
```

According to my lead the issue is with powershell script, when we manually uploads this xml as policy in APIM, its working. I feel the issue is with xml script only.Please help.

Powershell call below

```
if($VstsInputs.AddPolicy -eq 'true')
{
    Ges-Write-Log "Get the policy file"
    [xml]$Policies = Get-Content $VstsInputs.PolicyFile
```

Comment: Why are you showing us part of an xml making it an invalid xml?? If you want help, edit your question and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: To me policy looks fine and it doesn't seem to deal with any XML. Could you please share PS script? Also, clarify, when are you getting the error: while saving a policy, or while making a request to gateway.

Comment: please find the powershell script below  -- [xml]$Policies = Get-Content $VstsInputs.PolicyFile